# VB6 - Error 344 Indice para la matriz de objetos

Tags: vb6

Estoy intentando traducir un programa cargando texto desde la base de datos.
Tengo controles que son arreglos y otros que no.
El método funciona bien en los controles que no son arreglos.
En los controles que sí son arreglos me da un ERROR 344. No reconoce el indice para el control. Alguna solución?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaraciones:
A)Los controles simples o arreglos de controles están chequeados. Tal como están en vb se encuentran en la base de datos. En el campo indice de la bd se graban los indices que aparecen en el formulario. Si el indice es vacio corresponde a un control simple.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el código:

```
If Rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Rs.MoveFirst
    'Recorre el recordset para asignar el caption de los controles y objetos
    While Not Rs.EOF
        'Asigna el caption
        For Each ElControl In Controls
            Debug.Print ElControl.Name, IsControlArray(ElControl)
            'si está dentro lo deshabilita
            If ElControl.Name = Rs!nombre Then
                ' Agregar mas controles si es necesario
                If (TypeOf ElControl Is Label) Or _
                    (TypeOf ElControl Is Frame) Or _
                    (TypeOf ElControl Is CheckBox) Or _
                    (TypeOf ElControl Is OptionButton) Or _
                    (TypeOf ElControl Is Menu) Or _
                    (TypeOf ElControl Is CommandButton) Then
                    
                    'Asigna el caption
                    If Rs!indice <> "" Then
                    Dim i As Integer
                    i = CInt(Rs!indice)
                    
                        ElControl(i).Caption = Rs!texto
                    Else
                        ElControl.Caption = Rs!texto
                    End If
                ElseIf (TypeOf ElControl Is TextBox) Then
                    'si es un textbox, RichTexbox etc...
                    If Rs!indice <> "" Then
                        ElControl(Rs!indice).Text = Rs!texto
                    Else
                        ElControl.Text = Rs!texto
                    End If
                Else
                    'Error
                    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
                End If
            End If
        Next
        'Siguiente registro
        Rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End If
```

30/10/2020 16:12:00 **Adjunto todos los controles del formulario en cuestion.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

30/10/2020 17:08 **Ventana de inmediato. Con los valores consultados**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! el codigo escrito es distinto a la foto...

Comment: Tienes razon. Solo un control, pero que tiene indice. Como podría resolver eso ?

Comment: donde es que ves el indice?

Comment: Hago un pare en el codigo. En la ventana de inmediato escribo ?ElControl.index y devuelve 0 o 1.

Comment: entonces ya sabes el indice... no es un array de controles.. es un control que pertenece a un array de controles.. ahora que resolvimos eso.. arregla el codigo ;)